# ASP.net registration page with foreign keys and sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

For my assignment I'm supposed to create a registration page that's connected to a database. I'm using VS for Web 2012. However, I encountered a problem, when I run this page it actually loads, but when I press the submit button I get an error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
```

This error happens on this line:

```
int addressid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Any one know how I can fix this?
I attach my full code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["memberEmail"] = emailTB.Text;
        Session["name"] = firstNameTB.Text;
        Session["surname"] = surnameTB.Text;
        Session["password"] = passwordTB.Text;
        Session["phone"] = phoneTB.Text;
        Session["dob"] = dobTB.Text;
        Session["lineOne"] = lineOneTB.Text;
        Session["lineTwo"] = lineTwoTB.Text;
        Session["Town"] = townTB.Text;
        Session["County"] = countyTB.Text;
        Session["emEmail"] = emEmailTB.Text;
        Session["emName"] = emnameTB.Text;
        Session["emSurname"] = emSurnameTB.Text;
        Session["emNumber"] = emPhoneTB.Text;
        Session["healthInfo"] = medicalTB.Text;


    }
    protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            String connString = "Connection String deleted for security reasons ;)";
            SqlConnection regConn = new SqlConnection();
            regConn.ConnectionString = connString;
            regConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = regConn;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[address] ([lineOne],[lineTwo],[town],[county]) VALUES ('" + Session["lineOne"] + "," + Session["lineTwo"] + "','" + Session["Town"] + "','" + Session["County"] + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int)";
            int addressid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[emergencyContact] ([emergencyEmail],[emergencyContactName],[emergencyContactSurname],[emergencyContactNumber]) VALUES ('" + Session["emEmail"] + "','" + Session["emName"] + "','" + Session["emSurname"] + "','" + Session["emNumber"] + "')";


            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY AS string)";
            string emergencyEmail = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            emergencyEmail = emEmailTB.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[medicalInfo] ([physicalHealthInfo], [memberEmail]) VALUES ('" + Session["healthInfo"] + "')'";

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int)";
            int medid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[member] ([memberEmail],[name],[surname],[contactNumber], [dateOfBirth], [password],[medicalInfoID], [emergencycontactEmail], [addressID]) VALUES ('" + Session["email"] + "','" + Session["name"] + "','" + Session["surname"] + "','" + Session["phone"] + "'," + Session["dob"] + "','" + Session["password"] + "','" + Session["medInfo"] + "','" + medid + "','" + Session["emEmail"] + "','" + emergencyEmail + "','" + Session["addressID"] + "','" + addressid + "')'";

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY AS string)";
            string memberEmail = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            memberEmail = emailTB.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
            regConn.Close();
        }

        }
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability... Plus. you never execute the original `insert` query (you just overwrite the string with the scalar select), so there's no scope_identity to fetch...

Comment: You are setting the `cmd.CommandText` twice without running the command in between, I'm guessing that the select is returning `null` because nothing was inserted.

Comment: think he is just making this for a school project do don't think it matters how it works. SO MANY SESSIONS THOUGH WHY!!!

Comment: @KratosMafia yes, you are right I am making this for my college project, but I want to make it work.